# My PHP else { // statement }; doesn't show up when no results are found using LIKE in SQL (pictures provided)

Tags: javascript, php, sql, mysqli

```
<?php
include 'conn.inc.php';

$keyPressed = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['keyPressed']);


if (!empty($keyPressed)) {
    $sql = "SELECT name, type FROM businesses WHERE name LIKE '$keyPressed%' ORDER BY name";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<div class='businesses-bar'>
                <p class='businessName'>",
                    $row['name'],
                " (",$row['type'],")","</p>
                <button type='button'>PIN</button>
        </div>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
} else {
    echo "Search a business and click \"Pin\" to add it to the map.";
}
?>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

What I want to do should be pretty simple. I feel like I'm just missing a keyword or something.

- Get keystrokes from a javascript file and pass them through Ajax into this file, under the variable $keyPressed
- Find businesses by 'name' in my database
- Echo "0 Results" if keystrokes don't match any name in the database

Problem: Every time $keyPressed doesn't match a 'name', letter for letter, in my database column 'name', I get a blank return value(nothing prints to the screen). I want it to echo "0 results" if my keystrokes no longer match LIKE 'name' in my database.

I've tried putting the else statement at the end of

- if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)

hoping that if there are no results it will echo

- else {echo "0 results"};

but it's just echoing a blank space as if it's finding some sort of blank result.

All pictures of my issue are provided excluding the javascript file (which I know is not the issue).

Comment: `mysqli_query` returns some truthy value in case query executed correctly. Finding no matches is considered __correct__. What you need to check is __number of rows__ returned.

Comment: Don't use pictures of code, it's text just copy paste it into the question

Comment: Thank u_mulder, I had forgotten about number of rows... I just got back into PHP after a long break.

Comment: @PatrickEvans did you downvote me for using a picture?

Comment: Nope I don't downvote for those types of issues

Comment: @Ivar I'm not complaining. As you can see (or maybe not) that I'm new here. I didn't know you could edit a post or that posting a picture was a bad thing. Looking for the edit button now.

Comment: @Rob Thanks. If you are wondering why we dislike images here so much: see [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Comment: @Ivar Thanks for the info. It makes sense now why images can cause issues for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per PHP doc `mysqli_query()` For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.

try this

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) && mysqli_num_rows($result)){
 ...
}else{
 ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks suresh. Not all heros wear capes.